# Laravel 7.x Observer not saving, created_by updated_by user

Tags: laravel, observers

I have a Model named "Resource".

by using this command

```
php artisan make:observer ResourceObserver --model=Resource
```

this command create a new file, i update `created`, `updated` functions and update `constructor`

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Resource;

class ResourceObserver
{
    protected $userID;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userID = auth()->user()->id;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the resource "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Resource  $resource
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Resource $resource)
    {
        $resource->created_by = $this->userID;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the resource "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Resource  $resource
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Resource $resource)
    {
        $resource->updated_by = $this->userID;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the resource "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Resource  $resource
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(Resource $resource)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the resource "restored" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Resource  $resource
     * @return void
     */
    public function restored(Resource $resource)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the resource "force deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Resource  $resource
     * @return void
     */
    public function forceDeleted(Resource $resource)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

this is my migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            // some fields here
            $table->foreignId('created_by')->nullable()->default(null)->constrained('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreignId('updated_by')->nullable()->default(null)->constrained('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

then you should register the observer in `AppServiceProvider` like this:

```
use App\Observers\ResourceObserver;
use App\Resource;
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    Resource::observe(ResourceObserver::class);
}
```

Now the problem appears when update any record it is not save the `user_id`

to update i use `update` function in `ResourceController`

```
public function update(Request $request, Resource $resource)
{
    $validations = [
        // some validations
    ];
    $request->validate($validations);

    try {
        if (!empty($resource)) {
            $resource->field_a = $request->field_a;
            $resource->field_b = $request->field_b;
            $resource->field_c = $request->field_c;
            $resource->save();
            return 'done messge';
        } else {
            return 'error message';
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 'bug message';
    }
}
```

Any help please?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When issuing a mass update or delete via Eloquent, the `saved`, `updated`, `deleting`, and `deleted` model events will not be fired for the affected models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update or delete.

So, In `ResourceObserver` i just changed from method from `updated` to `updating`,
and `created` to `creating`

Comment: you are not doing a mass update (which would be calling `update` directly on the builder) ... you are just listening to events that happen after the model is already saved (hence the past tense 'created', 'updated') you would have to save the model again after this point, so choosing to go with `updating` and `creating` makes more sense for what you are doing